# clean dataframe according to multiple values disseminated in several columns

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I am trying to analyse a patient-based dataframe which was progressively filled over time with several lab values and the year they were sampled.

It basically looks like this, with lab values for example "A" and "B" which were sampled at visits 1 and 2:

```
df <- data.frame(Patient_Number=c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
A_Visit_1=c(23, 45, 23, 44),
A_Visit_2=c(35, 30, 50, 25), 
B_Visit_1=c(356, 234, 200, 150),
B_Visit_2=c(200, 350, 250, 230),
Visit_Year_1=c("2003","2004","2003","2004"),
Visit_Year_2=c("2004","2005","2005","2005")
)

   df
  Patient_Number A_Visit_1 A_Visit_2 B_Visit_1 B_Visit_2 Visit_Year_1 Visit_Year_2
1              1        23        35       356       200         2003         2004
2              2        45        30       234       350         2004         2005
3              3        23        50       200       250         2003         2005
4              4        44        25       150       230         2004         2005
```

To able to run analyses based on the years the patients were sampled, I'm looking to clean the dataframe and work with something that would look like this, with values arranged per year:

```
  Patient_Number A_2003 B_2003 A_2004 B_2004 A_2005 B_2005
1              1     23    356     35    200     NA     NA
2              2     NA     NA     45    234     30    350
3              3     23    200     NA     NA     50    250
4              4     NA     NA     44    150     25    230
```

Where for example for patient 1, value A in 2003 was 23 and since the patient wasn't sampled in 2005 it just returns "NA".

I've tried doing it with loops but it's really messy. Any suggestions? Thank you for the ideas.

Comment: I suggest that you convert your data to a long format with the columns `Patient_Number`, `Visit_Number`, `Visit_Year`, `Value`.

Comment: Are you sure your output is correct?

Comment: My bad, thank you, i corrected the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does it using `dplyr` and `tidyr` (although the columns are sorted differently).  It gathers columns `2:5` into long format, separates the values into `A or B` and the year number `1 or 2`, creates the new column headings, then uses these to convert back to wide format.  You could get the order you want by reversing the terms in the paste command, but the headings would then be `2003_A` etc.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df2 <- df %>% gather(key=visit, value=visitval, 2:5) %>% 
              separate(visit, into=c("AB", "YearNo"), sep="_Visit_") %>% 
              mutate(heading=paste(AB,
                    ifelse(YearNo==1, Visit_Year_1, Visit_Year_2), sep="_")) %>% 
              select(Patient_Number, heading, visitval) %>% 
              spread(key=heading, value=visitval)

df2
  Patient_Number A_2003 A_2004 A_2005 B_2003 B_2004 B_2005
1              1     23     35     NA    356    200     NA
2              2     NA     45     30     NA    234    350
3              3     23     NA     50    200     NA    250
4              4     NA     44     25     NA    150    230
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast. Thank you.

Comment: Altough when I run it, it returns "Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (1, 5), (2, 6), (4, 8), (9, 13), (10, 14), (12, 16)". What have I missed?

Comment: If you're using the `df` posted above you might need to add `,stringsAsFactors=FALSE` before the final `)` in the definition of `df`.  Otherwise it is comparing factor levels rather than the actual character values.